# Find the value of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k^{\alpha}}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Find the value of the expression $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k^{\alpha}}\right)$$
> where $\alpha$ is a positive number.

It is my first time seeing a question like this. Normally, we just put $n=\infty$ in the summand which is same as calculating the series till infinite terms.

But here it is different. The variable in the bound is also in the expression, meaning $n=\infty$ in the summand is not applicable in this case.

I expanded the series as $$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2^{\alpha}}+\cdots$$
But had no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the source of this question, please?

Comment: Consider bounds. If $\alpha=1$, you know the result. For $\alpha=2$, use partial fraction decomposition and use generalized harmonic numbers. The asymptotics is very simple. Then, induction, may be.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici But $\alpha$ is not a positive integer, it's a positive **number**.

Comment: @An_Elephant. Consider $\alpha=\pi$ and bound it by $3$ and $4$

Comment: @GerryMyerson i found it on a telegram group

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Ok sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suppose $a\in (0,1]$. Then
$${n\over {n+1}}\le \sum_{k=1}^n {1\over {a^k+n}}\le 1$$
and it follows that the limit equals $1$.

Now suppose $a>1$. Fixing $\epsilon>0$, we have
$$\sum_1^n {1\over {n+a^k}}=\sum_1^{\epsilon n} {1\over {n+a^k}}+\sum_{\epsilon n}^n  {1\over {n+a^k}}\le \epsilon+{n\over {a^{\epsilon n}}}<2\epsilon$$
when $n$ is large. Hence the limit equals $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the person who posted the problem has also given its solution, that I would like to share.

**The limit equals $1$ when $0<\alpha<1$, $\ln2$ when $\alpha=1$ and $0$ when $\alpha>1$**

$$\frac{1}{n+n^{\alpha}}<\frac{1}{n+1^{\alpha}}+\frac{1}{n+2^{\alpha}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n+n^{\alpha}}<\frac{n}{n+1}$$ and hence when $\alpha<1$ the limit equals $1$.

---

When $\alpha=1$ we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{dx}}{1+x}$$ $$=\ln2$$

---

When $\alpha>1$ we have since $n+k^{\alpha}\ge2\sqrt{n}k^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ that
$$0<\frac{1}{n+1^{\alpha}}+\frac{1}{n+2^{\alpha}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n+n^{\alpha}}<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{1}{1^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}+\frac{1}{2^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}\right)$$
An application of Stolź-Cesaro Lemma (the $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ case) shows that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{1^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}+\frac{1}{2^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}}{\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{(n+1)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}  {(n+1)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}=0$$

Comment: I don't understand the upper estimate in the case where $\alpha <1$. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @PhoemueX im sorry...i edited that

Comment: I see. I think the LHS is also missing a factor n. Thanks!